# SQL subquery return more that 1 value

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, subquery, row-number

Hi I am trying to execute a query to get row between certain number , Like i am trying to get rows between 10-20. so i am using subquery so that i can use `row_number()` function

The query fails with the error:

> SQL subquery return more that 1 value

So I need to figure a way out because I need to get more that 1 resulset out of the query

```
PROCEDURE dbo.Search

    (
    @search_text varchar(max), 
    @search_category varchar(max),
    @page int,
    @COUNT INT OUTPUT
    )

AS

     SET NOCOUNT ON
     DECLARE @Lower_limit int = (@page-1)*10;
     DECLARE @Upper_limit int = (@page * 10) + 1;
    -- SET @COUNT =0
     IF @search_category='deal'
     BEGIN
        SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dealData WHERE dealInfo LIKE  '%' + @search_text + '%' OR dealName LIKE '%' + @search_text + '%' OR dealDescription LIKE  '%' + @search_text + '%' GROUP BY dealId);
        SELECT x.dealId , x.ROW 
        FROM
        ( SELECT dealId,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dealId) as ROW from dealData WHERE dealInfo LIKE  '%' + @search_text + '%' OR dealName LIKE '%' + @search_text + '%' OR dealDescription LIKE  '%' + @search_text + '%'  GROUP BY dealId)x   
        WHERE x.ROW < @Upper_limit AND x.ROW > @Lower_limit
     END
```

This is the full procedure and when i try to call it from the following code I get exception at _command.ExecuteReader(); `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

```
 _query = "Search";
                _command = new SqlCommand(_query, _connection);
                _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search_text", search_text);
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search_category", search_category);
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page", page);
                var returnParameter = _command.Parameters.Add("@COUNT", SqlDbType.Int);
                returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                _reader = _command.ExecuteReader();
                while (_reader.Read())
                {
                    search_result index = new search_result();
                    index.category_id = this._categoryIdFromName(search_category);
                    index.post_id = _reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    _searchList.Add(index);
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is all your sql and that the above sql fails with the error you said? If not please post the actual SQL that returns the error message

Comment: What's the *problem*? What are you getting, and what do you want to get? This all looks correct so far.

Comment: When I try to run this procedure i get this exception `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`  But when i execute the procedure with same parameters from sql management studio i get the result expected

Comment: The SQL you've shown can't generate that error.  Are you calling it in a StoredProc?  Is it part of a Function?  Is `dealData` a view?  Is it embedded in a larger query?  Please include everything from the originating SQL call to the definition of all views, SProcs and functions.

Comment: @Amrit - `Please include everything from the originating SQL call to the definition of all views, SProcs and functions`...  Unfortunately `yes` isn't enough.  We need the code for the whole stored procedure, all views and functions called by that, etc, etc.  It seems quite clear that you believe you have narrowed the problem down to one query, unfortunately the error is *not* in that query directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this part of your sp:

```
SET @COUNT = (  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dealData 
                WHERE dealInfo LIKE  '%' + @search_text + '%' 
                OR dealName LIKE '%' + @search_text + '%' 
                OR dealDescription LIKE  '%' + @search_text + '%' 
                GROUP BY dealId)
```

Specifically, the `GROUP BY dealId` part. If you have multiple `dealId` on that table, then you are going to get multiple rows as a result. Obviously, you can't assign that on a scalar variable. Either `@Count` will need to be declared as a table variable (which will change the logic of the rest of your sp), or you get rid of the `GROUP BY dealId`, and verify that it gives you your desired results.

Comment: Group id is primary key so isn't it suppose to unique the result

Comment: @Amrit - You don't seem to understand the problem. If `dealId` is the primary key, then its easier to explain. If the conditions that you put on your `WHERE` returns more than one row as a result (let's suppose that it returns 3 rows), then, since you are grouping by the primary key, you will have 3 rows with a count value of 1, instead of 1 row with the count value of 3. And of course, the result that you are getting can't be assigned to a scalar variable.

Comment: Group by would return ... DealID = 1, Count = 3 | DealID = 2, Count = 2 | DealID = 3, Count = 5 ... etc

Comment: @Charleh - Not really, it would be: DealID = 1, Count = 1 | DealID = 2, Count = 1 | DealID = 3, Count = 1

Comment: @Amrit it has little to do with the fact that GroupID is the primary key. Think in terms of colored pencils. Your stored procedure is expecting *one count* of total pencils. You're giving it the count of blue, yellow, green, red, etc. pencils (which in any given box will be 1 of each, as Lamak's comment demonstrates).

Comment: @Lamak: Depends if the DealData table contained multiple rows for each deal :P - and if the CPU is faulty :D

Comment: @Charleh - As it was said on my comment (and Amrit seem to try to say the same on his/her previous comment), `dealId` is supposed to be the primary key of the table

Comment: Yeah I realised this after I posted it! I was just trying to explain visually :P - my bad!

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with @Lamak, and am only posting an answer so that repetition may inflict knowledge. If you re-write your assignment the following way, your problem will go away:

```
SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(*) 
  FROM dbo.dealData 
  WHERE dealInfo        LIKE '%' + @search_text + '%' 
     OR dealName        LIKE '%' + @search_text + '%' 
     OR dealDescription LIKE '%' + @search_text + '%' 
  /* GROUP BY dealId */ -- there is NO REASON for this grouping if you want total count!
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what everyone else has stated about the subquery that populates the variable returning multiple rows, there may be a more efficient means to get at what you seek (which I'm assuming is paging). This assumes that `GroupId` is the Primary Key of the `DealData` table as stated in comments:

```
Declare @Results Table
    (
    DealId ... not null Primary Key
    , RowNumAsc int not null
    , TotalCount int not null
    );

With NumberedData As
        (
        Select DealId
            , Row_Number() Over ( Order By GroupId ) As RowNumAsc
            , Row_Number() Over ( Order By GroupId Desc ) As RowNumDesc
        From DealData
        Where dealInfo LIKE  '%' + @search_text + '%' 
            Or dealName LIKE '%' + @search_text + '%' 
            Or dealDescription LIKE  '%' + @search_text + '%'  
        )
Insert @Results( DealId, RowNumAsc, TotalCount )
Select DealId, RowNumAsc
    , Min( RowNumAsc + RowNumDesc - 1 ) As Count
From NumberedData
Where RowNumAsc < @UpperLimit
    And RowNumAsc >= @LowerLimit
Group By DealId 

Set @Count = ( Select TOP 1 TotalCount From @Results );
Select DealId, RowNumAsc
From @Results
```